# Managing a large number of parallel iCloud accounts

Tags: iphone, icloud, contacts

I manage a large number (over 50) of unique iCloud accounts each with unique information, contacts, and an attached iPhone.
Currently any changes among the group's information has to be edited in manually, with contacts being the primary offender for time usage as I delete and then upload vCards for each account through the iCloud website.

Is there any workaround that Ask Different users know of? Any program that you have used or tried that could alleviate a bit of this workload?

Edit: As for clarification as to the system we have in place currently: we manage a number of field agents who need to be able to manage their own phone contacts on a parallel phone-by-phone basis, but all of the agents need to be able to contact one another, and the contact information among the agents changes frequently. It is a pain to update all of them manually through the current system we have in place. (iCloud) The number of agents we employ shifts with time, and we often deactivate phones and accounts, or even activate new ones, which would require an update to all of the phones' iCloud accounts, deleting outdated contacts and replacing them with the updated vCards. It feels as if there is a solution that could work better, but we have not been able to find it.

Comment: How did you manage to get yourself into this predicament? Wouldn't some kind of [corporate MDM](https://www.apple.com/business/dep/) structure be easier?

Comment: I think we need more information about the issue. What are the circumstances you bump into where you have to log in to a particular account to edit data manually?  You mentioned contacts, and I think one work-around is to have a macOS CardDAV server running instead of keeping the contacts in iCloud; that would at least allow easier administration, although it also wouldn't be perfect.  Profile Manager comes to mind but I'm not sure you can push Contacts through it.

Answer (score 1):

iCloud is hard to manage in enterprise setting. Even with Apple's own macOS server it is hard to manage this kind of thing. A better environment would be Office365 or Google Apps. In both systems it's really easy to manage large numbers of accounts. And add content to for example contacts.

If you really want to stick to iCloud. Make an Automator action would be the solution.

1. Login to an account
2. Delete content
3. Upload new content
4. Repeat with next account

Further more I highly recommand to [give feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/icloud.html) on this matter to Apple.